# Who was making silent calls?

Tags: plot-explanation, bug

In the beginning of the film "[Bug](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0470705/)" we can observe how Agness is plagued by silent calls, that she believes were made by her ex-spouse Jerry. Originally I thought it was Peter, who is kind of crazy paranoiac, so it was part of his reconnaissance of Agnes before revealing himself. However later on we can see that Peter himself answered another silent call, so it should be someone else.

I don't think it was Jerry (it seems to me that this character tends to express himself whenever possible rather than making silent calls), so I can't see any obvious answer here. Who could that be? What these calls were supposed for in the film at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Nobody**, as covered in [similar question's answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/31006/1190) already by Walt

> Agnes is angered by the fact that her phone keeps ringing and when she picks up, she hears no one and suspects it's her husband Jerry. Now, although this part could be explained in other ways, I believe this situation is set up to at least hint that there's a possibility her mental state is worse than we thought because the phone might've never rang: **Jerry denies calling her and the phone's lightbulb never even lights up when it rings**. So it's possible that the phone calls are imaginary, but even if they're not, they still might stand for Agnes's desire to hear from her missing kid and to also channel her anger at her husband.
>
> [image]

Comment: @TheDreamsWind Thanks the almighty [Walt](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/4386/walt)